# From what group do I need to pick this random number?

Tags: group-theory

I have the following definition of a finite group and subgroup of prime respectively safe prime order:

$\mathbb{G}_q \subset \mathbb{Z}_p^*$  with $p=563$ and $q=281$

In a protocol step, I have to pick the following random number:

$r \in_R  \mathbb{G}_p$

What does that mean? Do I need to pick a random quadratic residue modulo $563$ ? Or just a random number from $0$ to $562$ ?

Comment: What is $\mathbb G_p$ , a group with $563$ elements ? In this case, $r$ ist just a random element of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_{563}$ corresponding to a number from $0$ to $562$

Comment: Is that [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))? You usually pick $r$ such that $1<r<(p-1)(q-1)$ and $r,(p-1)(q-1)$ are coprime. This is because you will be looking for an inverse of $r$ modulo $(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: @freakish I don't see anything here to indicate that this should be RSA, since $563$ is a prime rather than a product of two primes.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft And why would it be a product od two primes? He uses two primes (and in one place a prime minus 1), uses a word "protocol" and looks for a random number somehow (not clear how) related to those primes. You wanna bet is about rsa?

Comment: @freakish I don't usually bet, but my bet would be on ElGamal here, rather than RSA.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft May be, may be. The game is on. :D